# Object preview not generated for large objects (bug?)

Tags: data-blocks

I have an issue with generating previews using *Batch-Generate Previews* for objects larger than around 60m. The object's thumbnail appears completely transparent in Blender file browser.

[image]

Can anyone confirm this is a bug? Is there a workaround?

I am using Blender 2.79.1.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I have reported that as a bug and it is going to be fixed soon.
https://developer.blender.org/T53002

Comment: Check your scene/viewport/camera clipping distances, it may be affecting the previews for very large objets

Comment: The clipping distance is set from 1cm to 1km, while the object is 60m. I even tried to enlarge the distance but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, so I have reported the bug on developer.blender.org and it was fixed in about 3 hours!

Link with the fix details:
https://developer.blender.org/rB63482a5f2e2ad76989c2d2901c1f34f2f0cb59d4

I have compiled the current Blender build which contains the fix and I can confirm the big object has now it's preview generated correctly.

[image]

This means a future public version will have this fixed as well.

Big thanks to Blender developers for such prompt reaction :)